# How to access to an ngModel element inside a reusable component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have an ngModel component inside my reusable component. The field is not part of a form. I would like to access to it to do some changes. I have tried the below code but it comes undefined in OnInit. Could you tell me how to access it ?

Below code returns undefined

```
@ViewChild('nameAccessor') ngModel:NgModel;
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.ngModel);
}
```

Template

```
<input ngModel (blur)="nameBoxChanged(nameAccessor)" (keyup)="nameBoxChanged(nameAccessor)" [ngClass]="{'redBorder':nameBoxValidator}"
      #nameAccessor [disabled]="pageStatus==4" name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'movieCategory.placeHolder.name'|translate}}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements which are tried to be got via `ViewChild` are not ready at the `OnInit` life cycle event. You can get the element in `AfterViewInit` life cycle event.

From the [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

> View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

Code block. Access your field in the `ngAfterViewInit` callback.

```
@ViewChild('nameAccessor') ngModel:NgModel;

ngOnInit(): void {

}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log(this.ngModel);
}
```

Comment: But if we create example we can see that ViewChild is set inside ngOnInit https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nkvgr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts It means that if ViewChild is static query then we can get its value inside ngOnInit

Comment: Interesting. So why documentation says about `ngAfterViewInit`? Maybe not every time it can be in OnInit ?

Comment: I think they forgot to update it. It was true for old view compiler

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/931cf78057068a28831acd0638e349d80d5e2f16/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L332-L336 Static content is filled during creation nodes

Comment: Maybe. Thanks for your comments

Comment: But static content can be only `ViewChild` not `ViewChildren` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0833b59aabddd541820379f3cbc69c62a5787bcc/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler/view_compiler.ts#L1078-L1080

Comment: Yeah, that's. Only ViewChild, but if it is "static query". For example if it is not inside *ngIf

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much

Comment: As mentioned by @Anik in another answer, `{ read: NgModel }` needs to be specified now.

Answer (score 4):

You also have to add `{read: NgModel}` with @ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('nameAccessor', {read: NgModel}) ngModel:NgModel;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Perhaps something changed since the Accepted answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

In ngOnInit, the @ViewChild are not yet setted. You should use ngAfterViewInit.