# Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'ElementRef' Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, viewchild

I have a template driven form with Angular 6. The form's component is nested within a parent component. In the form I have two input fields where I need to raise errors once the component is initiated (errors.required). So I have an event emitter.

I was looking for something similar to ngInit (from AngularJs) so I can call the function that emits the event up to parent component but couldn't find. So instead I need to do it in the component.

So in order to get the input fields in the component, I'm using ViewChild.

So my component looks something like:

```
@Component({ 
     selector: 'my-form',
     template: ... `<input ... #myInput="ngModel">` ....
})

export class myForm implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('myInput') private myInput: ElementRef;

 ...
 ...

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myInput.errors);
```

Then when I run the app I get this error:

**Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'ElementRef< any >**

I tried to do with `@ViewChild('myInput', {read: ElementRef})` and `console.log(this.myInput.nativeElement.errors);`

Still gets this error message.

Now, if I only console myInput, I'll not get the error message, and in the console I can see the errors key. One thing I noticed, it shows in the console: 
ngModel { ... ... errors: { ..

So I tried to log also myInput.ngModel.errors - still get the error

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805646/1009922) may solve your problem. Try `@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: NgModel;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access to an ngModel element inside a reusable component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805611/how-to-access-to-an-ngmodel-element-inside-a-reusable-component)

Comment: Thank you! Make sense. I also realized that if I do @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: any; the error also disappear. But I don't like to use any - kind of not the best practice.

Comment: so what is the reason for this? Why not ElementRef? I want to understand the reason

Comment: Because you define the variable as `#myInput="ngModel"`. If you had just defined `#myInput` by itself, it would refer to the HTML element (with the `ElementRef`).